# Large braces for specifying the condition for a mathematical result

Tags: delimiters, cases

I have a several condition for a mathematical results to be valid but I don't know how to put them in several lines with big braces after and then write some text.

```
$\beta_{1}>\epsilon_{1}$ \\
$\mu_{0}<0$\\
$ E_{2} <0$ \leftarrow the equilibrium point EP3 is stable
```

I coudn't find any think about this neither here or other places after some research.

Comment: I just forgot it here .

Comment: it is best if you always provide a complete small document that shows the problem, not just a fragment (then you would for example also notice that you have `\rightarrow` outside math mode which will generate an error.  It is helpful if code fragments don't have errors unrelated to the question.

Comment: Thanks I will do that next time. I wrote the code just to clarify my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\left.
\begin{aligned}
\beta_{1} &> \epsilon_{1}\\
\mu_{0}   &<0\\
E_{2}     &<0
\end{aligned}
\right\} \leftarrow \text{the equilibrium point $EP3$ is stable}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: yes,exactly thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `mathtools` package defines a `rcases` environment:

```
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath
........
\[ \begin{rcases}
\beta_{1}> epsilon_{1}  \\
 \mu_{0}<0 \\
 E_{2} <0
\end{rcases} 
\leftarrow \text{the equilibrium point EP3 is stable}
```

or with `empheq` (which loads `mathtools`):

```
\usepackage{empheq}
........
\begin{empheq}[right={\empheqrbrace \leftarrow \text{the equilibrium point EP3 is stable}]{align*}    
    \beta_{1}&> epsilon_{1}  \\
     \mu_{0} &< 0 \\
     E_{2} &< 0
\end{empheq}
```